# Ruby Program to print pattern

Tags: ruby

I have a hash and print that in the following Pattern :

Input 1 :

```
{
  a: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  b: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  c: [2,3,4,5,6,7]
}
```

Output 1 :

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6
   C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
```

Input 2 :

```
{
  a: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
  b: [2,3,4,5,6],
  c: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
}
```

Output 2 :

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7
   B2 B3 B4 B5 B6
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
```

For e.g.
If we consider Input 1 then the expectation is, the solution should add blank spaces at the missing number position.

=> It should return :

```
[
  ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9"], 
  ["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","","",""], 
  ["","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","",""]
]
```

Comment: `hash.map { |k, v| [k.to_s.upcase].product(v).map(&:join) } `

Comment: This gives the uppercase letters combined with the digit, but there is a blank space added at the missing number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use collection, map or each for this

```
data = {a: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],b: [1,2,3,4,5,6],c: [2,3,4,5,6,7]}
data.map{|k,v| (1..9).map{|a| data[k].include?(a) ? k.to_s.upcase() +a.to_s : ' '}}
```

Comment: This gives the uppercase letters combined with the digit, but there is a blank space added at the missing number.

Comment: data.map{|k,v| v.compact.map{|a| k.to_s.upcase() +a.to_s}}

Comment: you can compact the array to remove the missing one

Comment: need to add the missing one as a blank

Comment: Then you can check the conditions like this
data.map{|k,v| v.map{|a| a.to_i > 0 ? k.to_s.upcase() +a.to_s : ' '}}

Comment: Please provide the testcase

Comment: It should return :
[["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9"],["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","","",""],["","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","",""]]

Comment: num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
data.map{|k,v| num.map{|a| data[k].include?(a) ? k.to_s.upcase() +a.to_s : ' '}}

Comment: or data.map{|k,v| (1..9).map{|a| data[k].include?(a) ? k.to_s.upcase() +a.to_s : ' '}}